# ¿Cómo uso el valor total de dos columnas de dos diferentes consultas en una nueva consulta?

Tags: base-de-datos, ms-access

[image: Consulta PRESUPUESTO_DEP]

[image: Consulta PRESUPUESTO_DEP]

En la consulta PRESUPUESTO_DEP tengo el presupuesto total asignado a una dependencia. En la consulta PEDIDO_DEP tengo aquellos servicios que solicitó la dependencia y el importe total por todos los servicios. Mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo usar los totales (los valores señalados con flechas azules) en una nueva consulta con el fin de saber si aquello que la dependencia pidió no sobrepasa o sí su presupuesto?

Comment: Con una consulta de agrupación. (GROUP BY) O puedes llevártelo a un informe y compararlos ahí. O mediante macros.

Comment: Puedes crear una consulta intermedia que solo contenga los totales de cada dependencia y su Id para utilizarlos luego donde quieras.